# can i install and run an older kernel (3.10) within a latest ubuntu release (14.04)?

Tags: kernel, 14.04

I would like to install 3.10.34 (http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.10.34-saucy/linux-image-3.10.34-031034-generic_3.10.34-031034.201403240135_amd64.deb ) in my current ubuntu 14.04 64bits install

but is that possible ? (i ask because it's mentioned as a saucy kernel on http://kernel.ubuntu.com & i know nothing about kernel architecture, dependencies and relationships to ubuntu releases)

i'd like to keep the latest kernel installed and chose the kernel to boot on start-up

[why is that you may ask :

latest kernel is messing with hdmi sound output on my system (distorted, reedy) and the last working kernel is 3.10.34 it'd seem (from another user that has the same problem) so i want to have both kernel, working on one, updating the other until the issue is fixed - at which point i'll remove 3.10.34]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Normally the system will use the latest kernel available. You can change the default kernel by configuring GRUB, or at each computer start-up press SHIFT and keep it pressed until you see the GRUB menu where you can choose the kernel you want.